# .Net Website Error loading a Type from a DLL

Tags: .net, dll, load, .net-assembly

We have a .Net website on IIS. Windows server 2012 R2. .Net 4.6.1

When we try to run it, it throws this error:

> Could not load type 'CodeSmith.Data.Linq.DataContextBase' from assembly 'CodeSmith.Data, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=596a5eee5d207fdd'.

That DLL is in the Bin folder of the website and it is also in the GAC. Yet the error still happens. I have opened the DLL in ILSpy to make sure the referenced type is in there and it is.

Can anyone offer any advice or ideas about a direction I could take to at least find out what's happening?

Turned on FusionLog and get this error:

> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x1. Incorrect function. Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under executable C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe --- A detailed error log follows. BEGIN : Native image bind. END : Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x00000001 (S_FALSE))

Thanks!

Comment: See [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Comment: Thanks! Did that found a file with the referenced DLL in the name with this error inside:  The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x1. Incorrect function.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

BEGIN : Native image bind.
END   : Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x00000001 (S_FALSE))

Comment: Not much info there.

Comment: Edit the new information into your question please.